# Increasing the Rate of Multiple Births in Humanoids?

Tags: biology, evolution, fantasy-races, reproduction, sex

What factors would cause a humanoid race (like, say, goblins, just to throw an example out there) to have a significantly higher rate of multiple births than the human norm? Presumably a large mortality rate for children in the past might be a factor, but what else could contribute to such a result?

Comment: Very related: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/54535/how-can-i-determine-the-litter-size-of-a-species

Answer (score 3):

There is a strong genetic basis for multiple births in modern mammals so if infant mortality is high but multiples tend to produce at least one survivor while singletons almost always die then you might expect to see multiple births become the norm in just a few generations as the genes for multiple births become [fixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixation_(population_genetics)) in the population. The rapid fixation is caused by the fact that the population is effectively [bottle-necked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_bottleneck) by the mortality rate.

Comment: So, it would only take a century or two at most for that to happen? What kind of scenario might feasibly cause this in humanoids (especially if they're related to humans somehow)?

Comment: @Preg-Fan Could be two or three generations (50-75 years in humans). That I'm not sure about, historically multiples are in fact less likely to survive under circumstances of high infant mortality not more likely. I can think of some cultural practices that would do it and obviously a "natural" population bottleneck could cause the effect as a random side-effect.

Comment: We'll come back to the cause of the multiples thing. What could cause such a "natural" bottleneck?

Comment: @Preg-Fan Famine, flood, pestilence, any major natural disaster that kills a large number of people all at once. Or [Founder Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Founder_effect) which is a special case of a bottleneck in which it's caused by the selection of colonists. In either case the population on the other side of the restriction event has a lowered genetic diversity than the parent group it draws it's members from.

Comment: What's the minimum size a such group would need to be for the multiple births trait to propagate through the group in the mentioned timeframe before they would need a new infusion of fresh genes from another group to prevent inbreeding, do you think?

Comment: @Preg-Fan Pass, different models will tell you different things and to a large degree the real world answer will depend heavily on the prevalence of damaging recessive genes in the population and the mating practices of the group in question.

Answer (score 2):

Fantasy goblins typically live in lands that have limited resources, typically swamps, or cold rocky deserts, where mortality rates from poisonous bugs, predators, accidents, etc are high. Being smaller than humans this raises their mortality rate from predators even higher. 
So a large number of children is almost essential for the survival of the species.

While fantasy goblins have been shown to be able to eat some plants, they are primarily meat eaters. Being less picky than humans in their source of food, combined with being smaller so needing less nourishment, even in their resource poor areas, there will be food, even if its just a bowl full of minnows, bugs and larva. Since they can also eat some plants, they likely supplement their diet with roots, berries and some greens. So as long as they aren't going through a drought or famine, they should have enough food, especially protein and carbs that the mothers won't be badly malnourished which will help with fertility.

Now the main limiting factor for babies is feeding them. Since they only drink milk for the first several months and still rely on it for anywhere from a year and a half to 5 years depending on the culture, the mother has to put a huge amount of resources into the child and having two can strain things.

Having to have large families to keep ahead of the death rate, and needing the children to mature quickly to keep from wearing out the mother, relying solely on milk is not a good idea. What if the babies are capable to drinking well crushed and partially digested bugs and meat alongside milk?

Bugs are almost always available so while the mother is nursing two or three babies, she is eating a large amount of bugs. An hour or two later when the babies are hungry again, instead of giving them a breast, she gives them a few mouthfuls of her last meal. This mixed diet is easier for the mother to handle, and the regurgitation could be done by other females acting as nursemaids even if they don't have children of their own.

As a survival strategy, if they are running out of food, the mother could abandon or eat the weaker sibling/s, so at least one child should survive.

So living in regions with high mortality, but with an abundance of bugs, grubs and small animals most humans would ignore, and making the babies able to eat predigested bugs alongside milk, would allow goblin mothers to have twins or triplets without impacting the brain size of the babies or wearing out the mother.

Comment: Goblins were just an example I used, since they're depicted as being rather quick to increase their numbers in some media, but most of the information in here is helpful. I'm not sure about the bug thing though, even if early weaning is a good idea. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I couldn't really see myself typing hobbits or gnomes as a name for a species that feeds its babies regurgitated bugs. It just didn't seem to fit. 
With humans some Africans have twins with every 1 in 20 births, that's the max number seen in humans. The problem is that the brains require too much energy for the mother to keep supplying in the womb. Any small species with human-like intellect will have the same problem. Even most monkeys and primates have only 1 or possibly 2 babies at a time. The early weaning is the best method to provide the necessary nutrients without undue stress on mom.

Comment: What could cause early weaning to develop like that then? I'd imagine a lower mortality rate among babies that wean early would certainly help, but what else?

Comment: Mostly just the fact that babies who could be weaned earlier meant they survived and were better nourished, while the mother could have more babies sooner. With the addition that other women in the family or tribe could help out, it really eased the burden on the mother ensuring she was healthier and more likely to survive in the long term. Given a long enough time period the babies became similar to baby birds, able to eat pre-digested food almost from the day they are born.